# .htaccess question

Tags: html, drupal, .htaccess, redirect

Recently changed CMS from jShop to Drupal and because jShop uses sessions I am getting a lot of visitors to my website through pages like these :-

```
page.php/privacypolicy/a9d08247d84a70a425dccf15e7e1f61b
page.php/privacypolicy/3091d422e0d5a61328329979dab8f10f
```

As you can see, the session ID is always changing so I'm having trouble redirecting the old private policy page to the new one using `.htaccess`.

Is there any way I can ignore the last part of the URL and force it to redirect anything that is `page.php/privatepolicy/`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I want it to redirect to "private-policy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    # page.php/privacypolicy/abcd123... -> private-policy
    RewriteRule page\.php/privacypolicy.+ private-policy [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What other rules do you have in your htaccess?

Comment: I just have some redirects from old pages to the new paths. Nothing relating to privatepolicy.

Comment: Updated my code, please check again, and tell me what exactly happens when you visit the page `page.php/privacypolicy/a9d08247d84a70a425dccf15e7e1f61b`. Also, in order to be able to give the most appropriate solution, please give examples with a sample domain (e.g. I want to ridirect from `site.com/page.php/privacypolicy/a9d08247d84a70a425dccf15e7e1f61b` to `site.com/page.php/private-policy/`.

Comment: The redirects from the old pages to the new paths might affect, that's why I asked. You definitely must have some rules which rewrite `page.php/var...` to `page.php?parm=var...`, or you are asking with the wrong examples.

Comment: Hi Shef, my domain is www.ensorbuilding.com so when somebody access for example, www.ensorbuilding.com/page.php/privacypolicy/a9d08247d84a70a425dccf15e7e1f61b , I want to redirect them to www.ensorbuilding.com/private-policy but I want to redirect anything that starts with page.php/privacypolicy so that it doesn't matter that the session ID is. Hope this makes it clearer for you!

Comment: I have caching in the htaccess to seed my site up and the basic drupal rules, not sure if I can post it on here?

Tried your updated code and it still is displaying page not found

Comment: @Dan: Try the updated code. The rewrite rule should precede any other rule in your htaccess file.

Comment: Shef you are a genius, working correctly now. Thanks for your help and apologised for not making myself clearer :) Have a great day!

Comment: @Dan: [Doesn't seem to work](http://www.ensorbuilding.com/page.php/privacypolicy/a9d08247d84a70a425dccf15e7e1f61b). If you don't have `RewriteBase /` add it just after `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: @Dan: Okay, seems to be working perfectly fine now. Since it seems like it solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking on the tick below the vote count on the left hand side of my answer.